# How to read dynamic object values

Tags: c#

How to read propertyValues attributes?

```
    public void Create(object propertyValues)
    {
        //How to read propertyValues attributes?
        //int code = propertyValues.Code;
        //string name = propertyValues.ProductName;
    }

    public void CallMethod()
    {
        Create(new
        {
            Code = 100,
            ProductName = "P1",
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you confusing dynamic typing and anonymous types? If you want a method that takes in an instance of the type and reads from the properties, use a named type (usual class or struct) and not an anonymous type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `object` parameter to be `dynamic` or create a strongly typed version of the object you are trying to pass

```
public void Create(dynamic propertyValues)
{
    int code = propertyValues.Code;
    string name = propertyValues.ProductName;
}
```

or

```
public void Create(Order propertyValues)
{
    //How to read propertyValues attributes?
    var code = propertyValues.Code;
    var name = propertyValues.ProductName;
}

public class Order{
    public int Code {get; set;}
    public string ProductName {get; set;}
}

public void CallMethod()
{
    Create(new Order
    {
        Code = 100,
        ProductName = "P1",
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `dynamic`

```
public void Create(dynamic propertyValues)
{
    int code = propertyValues.Code;
    string name = propertyValues.ProductName;
}
```

Or `Reflection`:

```
public void Create(object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    int code = (int)type.GetProperty("Code").GetValue(obj);
    string name = (string)type.GetProperty("ProductName").GetValue(obj);
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer for the question that was asked. +1 for actually showing how to get properties from an object instead of (just use dynamic).

Comment: using reflection is generally not something you want to do in general development, it is expensive, error prone, and often leads to code that is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dynamic` type:

```
public void Create(dynamic propertyValues)
{
    //How to read propertyValues attributes?
    int code = propertyValues.Code;
    string name = propertyValues.ProductName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick

```
public void Create(object propertyValues)
{
    // dummy value for the right type
    var o = new { Code = 0, ProductName = "P", };
    o = Cast(o, propertyValues);
    Console.WriteLine(o.ProductName);
}

public void CallMethod()
{
    Create(new
    {
        Code = 100,
        ProductName = "P1",
    });
}

private static T Cast<T>(T type, Object value)
{
    return (T)value;
}
```

The trick is that inside the assembly, the same anonymous type resolves to the same type.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) definition:

> If two or more anonymous object initializers in an assembly specify a sequence of properties that are in the same order and that have the same names and types, the compiler treats the objects as instances of the same type. They share the same compiler-generated type information.